# Min and max button and label

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to build a exam grader using C#. I'm new to this and don't know very much. What code would I use to add min and max buttons and to add a label stating whether it's a min or max?

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int points;
    try
    {
        points = int.Parse(txtPoints.Text);
        lstPoints.Items.Add(points);
        txtPoints.Clear();
        txtPoints.Focus();
        if (lstPoints.Items.Count == 12)
        {
            txtPoints.Enabled = false;
            btnAdd.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (lblResult.Text != "")
        {
            lblResult.Text = "";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter only whole numbers");
        txtPoints.Clear();
        txtPoints.Focus();
    }
}

private void btnAvg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lstPoints.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        total += (int)lstPoints.Items[i];
    }
    total /= lstPoints.Items.Count;
    lblResult.Text = total.ToString(); 
}

private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstPoints.Items.Clear();
    txtPoints.Enabled = true;
    btnAdd.Enabled = true;
}
}
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `lstPoints.Items[i]` ?

Comment: at which line exception occurring??

Comment: Its occurring at this line   total += (double)lstPoints.Items[i];

Comment: I changed it the double to int and it worked. I still need help on the min and max button.

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you now? It looks like you already know how to add buttons and labels on the form so I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 1):

hope this works

```
private void getMax()
{
   int max=0;
   for (int i = 0; i < lstPoints.Items.Count; i++)
        {
             if(max<(int)lstPoints.Items[i])
                 {
                     max=(int)lstPoints.Items[i];
                 }
        }

        lblResult.Text = max.ToString(); 
        }

}

private void getMin()
{
   int min=(int)lstPoints.Items[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < lstPoints.Items.Count; i++)
        {
             if(min>(int)lstPoints.Items[i])
                 {
                     min=(int)lstPoints.Items[i];
                 }
        }

        lblResult.Text = min.ToString(); 
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possiblities as I see:

> 1) When you are writing this:
>
> ```
> lstPoints.Items.Add(points);
> ```
>
> Instead of adding to `List(Of Integer)` use [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx). So the
>   list will always have the sorted result sets.
>
> 2) Use `Array.Sort()` to sort the records.

Once you have sorted records the first one is the minimum and the last one is the maximum (Assuming sorted in ascending order).

Take out two buttons and placed on the form, set `Text` Property from property window to `Min` and `Max` respectively and in event handler handle the `Click` event and pick the relevant resultset from `lstPoints` array.

Hope it helps!